# React generic onChange withing object

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm in this typical situation:

```
 onChange(name) { 
    return (event) => { 
      this.setState({
           [ name] :  event.target.value 
      }, () => this.props.onChange(this.state));
    };
  }
...
 <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.fieldName}
            onChange={( ) =>this.onChange('fieldName')}  
            />
```

But I would like to achieve something like:

```
 onChange(name) { 
    return (event) => { 
      this.setState({
           fieldObj.[ fieldName] :  event.target.value 
      }, () => this.props.onChange(this.state));
    };
  }
...
 <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.fieldObj.fieldName}
            onChange={( ) =>this.onChange('fieldName')}  
            />
```

But it's not working. I'm not sure this can be done, but that would save me a lot of work on forms with lots of fields.

Comment: Something like this should work, this.setState({ fieldObj :{ [ fieldName] : event.target.value }} since its an object within object.

Comment: There's 2 defects here. 1) your onChange event needs to be binded, otherwise `this` won't match to the component instance. 2) you have a inline callback FormControl's onChange, but you already have taken care of that with your `onChange` function.

Comment: And since you wouldn't want to update the whole fieldObj object, use spread operator to keep the existing values like this, { fieldObj : {...this.state.fieldObj, [fieldName] : event.target.value}}

Comment: perfect! put this as an answer and I'll accept it!